# how to profile the number of arithmetic operations in a C/C++ program?

Tags: floating-point, profiler, integer-arithmetic

Is there any way to profile the total number of arithmetic operations used in a certain C/C++ program? By arithmetic operations I mean any operation that uses the integer/floating/special arithmetic unit in hardware.

Comment: There is no general portable mechanism for counting operations performed by a process. Various systems have methods for doing this, often as special hardware debugging features that require administrator privileges to use and/or require special interfaces. They also often require detailed technique knowledge of the processor or its architecture.

Comment: create classes myint,myfloat,mydouble ... as wrapers for int,float,double,... and count operations in them.... in meassured program just replace all int,float,double by myint,myfloat,mydouble ...

Comment: @Spektre This sounds like a good idea but it will require a manual replacement for all the arithmetic operations in a source code, and might not be accurate due to different compiler behavior. And it does not work when there is no source code for the program.

Comment: no manual replacement needed (replace all in source code) and operations are the same on the same type so with the same output, but yes you need source code (you wrote  in C/C++ so i assumed that is not an issue). if you want to check exe/dll or what ever than only option is emulation and count aritmethic,SSE,MMX,... or FPU instructions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is on intel X86-64 architecture, I would suggest to use pin tools: [PIN for Ubuntu](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool). There has been a plug-in built, namely, [MICA](http://kejo.be/ELIS/mica/) on top of it which can instrument independently. One of the 99 outputs is exactly "Floating-point". Look into "Arithmetic-control flows" and "SSE/MMX" as well since based on the compiler different registers are being used. This makes sure you are monitoring all floating points.

Comment: let me know if that helps you so you could accept the answer in case someone else wanted to use ;)

Comment: It looks as though the MICA link is now someone's personal blog. Is this the correct link? 
https://github.com/boegel/MICA